# MongoDB SSL Enabling/Configuration

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I have created self signed Certificated by using openssl and have mongodb.pem(mongodb.key + mongodb.cert) file generated from openssl. Also i have my mongodb-ssl.conf file as follows

```
storage:
   dbPath: C:\Users\rajshanb\MongoDB\data\db\
net:
   port: 27018 
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   ssl:
       Mode = requireSSL
       PEMKeyFile = C:\Users\rajshanb\mongodb.pem
       PEMKeyPassword = rajshanb
       CAFile = C:\Users\rajshanb\client.pem
```

But when i am trying to start the server from terminal :

```
C:\Users\rajshanb\MongoDB\mongodb\bin>mongod -f C:\Users\rajshanb\mongodb-ssl.conf
Unrecognized option: net.ssl
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

I'm getting above mentioned error. Please help me to identify whether i am missing something in configuration.

I am having installed MongoDB version as :

```
C:\Users\rajshanb>mongod --version
db version v3.4.6
git version: c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: enterprise
build environment:
    distmod: windows-64
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

That `Mode` should be `mode`, so no Capital first letter.

Those `=` should be `:`

Answer (score 0):

its an spacing issue in configuration definition here are my working configurations

```
net:
  port: 28017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb/mongodb-server.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb/mongodb-client.pem
    PEMKeyPassword: abc123+
```